# How to disable the auto-reconnect feature with sshfs?

Tags: macos, rsa, sshfs

I am using `sshfs` to have a file system mounted on my Mac. Every time my internet connection drops, it gets disconnected, and then tries to reconnect again periodically once the internet connection is back up.

The problem is that I need to enter an RSA token in order to log in, and so every time it tries to reconnect, that connection is denied, because I am not entering a new RSA token.

How to I make it stop to auto-reconnect?

Browsing online, I see that this feature should be off by default, so I am a bit lost. (I don't have `ServerAliveInterval` or `ServerAliveCountMax` in my `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` files, nor I am passing `-o reconnect` to `sshfs`).

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? Am having the same issue, but get blocked after failed reconnect attempts..

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't...